# PCB mounting holes outer chainring

Tags: mounting-holes

A curiosity, but why do the mounting holes on PCBs have those small holes on the outer chainring?

I mean these:
[image]

Comment: Those are vias to connect the outer layer seen in the image to other layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are for electrical conductivity.

They allow to connect the copper area of the mounting hole electrically between different copper layers, to have a good connection from the metallic screw on top and metallic chassis mounting stand to ground plane.

Comment: If  good connection from the metallic screw on top and metallic chassis is required then why isn't the fastener hole plated thru ?

Comment: @DDuck maybe because that could eventually wear off. Which is an extremely unlikely scenario...

Comment: @DDuck That is a very valid question.

Comment: The question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/137394/mounting-hole-on-a-pcb shows a photo of a variety of mounting holes, one with a ring of vias surrounding a plated thru hole and one without.  And pretty well explains that the main hole isn't plated thru to avoid small metal particles being generated -- and that the vias are for electrical conductivity and mechanical stiffness to avoid the bearing pad from lifting off.

Comment: @DDuck Impossible to know why. There might be a good reason but we don't know why that board does not have a large plated through mounting hole. The nearest PCB that I am looking at does have a large plated through mounting hole.